# ESRI Proportion tool/command and ArcFM split configuration

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcfm

In my project we are using ArcGIS 10.1 and ArcFM 10.1. 
I have requirement that

"If customer use Proportion Tool to split abandon liner feature then action need to assign new GISID (attribute) to shorter segment(s) only. (none of other attributes should need to be updated)"

To satisfy this requirement I should need to build new **AutoUpdater**.

Currently I know if we use **ESRI split Tool** then it's fires split events of ArcFM (BeforeFeaturesplit, OnFeaturesplit, OnFeaturecreate(for new segement), AfterFeatureSplit).

but While using the **Proportion Tool**it's just fires only 
OnFeatureCreate event.

Comment: is ArcFM Configuration supports the multiple splits ?